# error when installing nginx from source with ssl support

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to install nginx 1.7 from source with ssl support within my ubuntu 15.10 setup.

Here is configure command:

```
./configure --user=www --group=www --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module
```

No error reported for configure, but issue comes from make:

[image]

Seems to be related to openssl. 
I checked that I have installed openssl, libssl-devel, libssl1.0.0

How to fix this guy?

Thanks.

Wesley

Comment: 1.7 is not even mentioned in the legacy versions, the last stable is 1.8 ; I'd try again with 1.8 (see http://nginx.org/en/download.html ). Btw are you using gcc? pointer "signedness" is usually a warning, at worst.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe openssl version is too high for nginx 1.7, I changed to 1.8 and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NGIИX version 1.7 doesn't seem reliable

- it's not listed in the legacy versions of [NGIИX download](http://nginx.org/en/download.html)
- the last stable version is 1.8

So you should try again with the latest stable version, `1.8`.